# Passing variables from selenium-side-runner

Tags: selenium, selenium-side-runner

Given this very simple Selenium test:

[image: Selenium side script with username and password]

How can the username and password variables be provided while running the .side project using the selenium-side-runner? Either as command line parameters, statically typed on the .side.yml configuration file or coming from an external data file. Any option other than having the user credentials hardcoded in the .side file.

For reference, here is the content of .side file:

```
{
  "id": "2fcada56-fdb1-4acd-9d95-451e3d74c8f3",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "Todo",
  "url": "https://www.todo-cloud.com/",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "8e83c690-453d-4602-b187-015e9ee4cfe7",
    "name": "Login",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "453101ad-3249-47e9-bc87-860bbfdea343",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "https://www.todo-cloud.com/#/welcome/login",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "f14304b6-4f66-4b79-b1a5-39bd206f29af",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "name=username",
      "targets": [
        ["name=username", "name"],
        ["css=.ng-valid", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//input[@name='username']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "${username}"
    }, {
      "id": "a2520d2d-100b-4be4-93f7-d88f3ede804a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "name=password",
      "targets": [
        ["name=password", "name"],
        ["css=.password", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//input[@name='password']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[2]/div/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "${password}"
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "31c08a71-044c-4917-87e8-fcaacf3cd7ac",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["8e83c690-453d-4602-b187-015e9ee4cfe7"]
  }],
  "urls": ["https://www.todo-cloud.com/"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature request in the selenium side project on GitHub, if I am not mistaken.

In the meantime, as a workaround, I would suggest using a pre-process.

Since .side files are JSON outputs, you can:

- retrieve the JSON object contained in the .side file,
- find the variable you want to modify
- assign the new value
- rewrite your new JSON object into a json file before renaming it with a .side  extension

Comment: I ended up creating a batch script that accepts parameters, does a search and replace on the selenium script, generates a new file, runs it and then deletes it.